# Switch Statement Returns 0

Tags: switch-statement, ms-access-2013

Why is my switch statement returning a 0 for all matched values instead of the "switch" value?  If it is not a matched value then it returns blank, which is correct.

Here is my syntax, which looks valid to my newbie eye

```
SELECT [ICC]=Switch([ICC]="UV1","RP1",[ICC]="UV2","RP2",[ICC]="UV3","RP3") AS Expr1
FROM UVMaster;
```

Comment: Are you trying to change the value of `[ICC]` to the value returned by the Switch?

Comment: @EdPlunkett yes, if ICC = UV1 then show RP1, if ICC=UV2 then show RP2, if ICC=UV3 then show RP3

Comment: You need an update to change the value in the table. Select will just interpret that `=` as a comparison, and I think it's returning `0` for "false", because the new value doesn't equal the old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the [ICC]= in the beginning of your Switch Statment. It should look like the below. Can't answer why its returning a zero, but this should fix it.

```
SELECT Switch([ICC]="UV1","RP1",[ICC]="UV2","RP2",[ICC]="UV3","RP3") AS Expr1
FROM UVMaster;
```

Comment: That got it!  To soon to accept as answer.  Thank you!

Comment: I realize now what I did, I needed an update statement but was testing with a Select first to ensure proper syntax.  So my update would actually read Update UVMaster Set ICC=switch....while the Select statement only reads Select switch...

Comment: Makes sense, simple mix up. Do me a favor and mark the answer when it becomes available. And No Problem!